# How to create one app(driver with prerequisites) without creating app for driver and app for prerequisite in Advanced Installer?

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, advanced-installer

## **How to create one app with prerequisites in Advanced Installer?**

Hello,

I'm facing problem about prerequisites in Advanced installer. I want to install prerequisites with driver and if user wants to uninstall it all, You can just uninstall one app in "apps and features".
At the moment my installer does "2 apps in apps and features":
[image]

Due to this problem, I'cant move forward and also I don't know what to do and I have't found any useful article about this. I expect that installer will create one app in "apps and features"
and uninstall prerequisites and driver itself by one button, not one by one.

Please help. I'm grateful for every help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want your setup be listed in "Apps & Features" you should uncheck "Register product with Windows Installer" option in "Product Details" view of your setup project.